# Finding an invariant $\mu(x,y)=\mu\big(xy,\frac{y-x}{xy}\big)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations, invariance

I am trying to find a (nontrivial) function $\mu$ satisfying the functional equation
$$\mu(x,y)=\mu\bigg(xy,\frac{y-x}{xy}\bigg)$$
In case anybody wants to know, I plan on using $\mu$ to simplify and analyze the behaviors of the sequences
$$\theta_{n+1}=\theta_n\phi_n,\space\space\space \phi_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\theta_n}-\frac{1}{\phi_n},\space\space\space \theta_0=\phi_0=1$$
Does anyone know how to find nontrivial $\mu$ satisfying the functional equation?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the sequences make much sense - $\phi_1 = 0$, so the equation for $\phi_2$ contains a $1/0$ term.